# Using XPath to delete and write new nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I wish to remove then add new nodes/values to an Xml file.

Here is a shortened version of the Xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NinjaTrader>
    <OpenWorkspaces>
        <OpenWorkspace>OldWorkspace1</OpenWorkspace>
        <OpenWorkspace>OldWorkspace2</OpenWorkspace>
    </OpenWorkspaces>
</NinjaTrader>
```

So basically I want to remove all children of OpenWorkspaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NinjaTrader>
   <OpenWorkspaces>
   </OpenWorkspaces>
</NinjaTrader>
```

Then I want to add new nodes and values. *The values "NewWorkspace1 to NewWorkspace4" will come from a string array.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NinjaTrader>
   <OpenWorkspaces>
       <OpenWorkspace>NewWorkspace1</OpenWorkspace>
       <OpenWorkspace>NewWorkspace2</OpenWorkspace>
       <OpenWorkspace>NewWorkspace3</OpenWorkspace>
       <OpenWorkspace>NewWorkspace4</OpenWorkspace>
   </OpenWorkspaces>
</NinjaTrader>
```

The reason I want to remove the children then make new ones is because I may have a different number of them from the original as the above example shows.

So I've tried using 'Remove' to start with:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(myPath);
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//OpenWorkspaces").Descendants("OpenWorkspace").Remove();
```

All that does is this:

```
<NinjaTrader>
    <OpenWorkspaces />
</NinjaTrader>
```

I am fairly competent at C# but not Xml. I have spent several hours experimenting with XPath extensions but getting a little frustrated with the results. So a push in the right direction would be very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have done the delete part, adding new elements can be done by projecting your array of string to a series of `XElement`s and pass the result to [`XElement.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345077(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here is a minimal but complete example :

```
var raw = @"<NinjaTrader>
    <OpenWorkspaces>
        <OpenWorkspace>OldWorkspace1</OpenWorkspace>
        <OpenWorkspace>OldWorkspace2</OpenWorkspace>
    </OpenWorkspaces>
</NinjaTrader>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
List<string> newValues = new List<string>{"NewWorkspace1","NewWorkspace2","NewWorkspace3"};

var ow = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//OpenWorkspaces");

ow.Descendants("OpenWorkspace").Remove();
ow.Add(newValues.Select(o => new XElement("OpenWorkspace", o)));

Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BqDUq4)</kbd>**

Comment: I simply substituted: var xdoc = XDocument.Load(myPath); for var raw. I up-marked your answer but it won't show for me yet since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem. Ticking the check mark is enough for now. You can always come back to upvote once you got enough rep, if you want